# The compliance properties of the elements of the array by i

Tags: javascript, arrays, canvas

On canvas I've allocated an array of stars with coordinates:

```
x: randomInt(1, canvas.width - 1),
y: randomInt(0, canvas.height - 1),
```

Every star has an initial opacity (`op`) value of 1. During animation, the opacity changes to 0 (and the stars disappear).

It should be that stars in the top part of the canvas (`y < 75`) disappear at a different speed from those at the bottom, because of the following code that sets the opacity values for each frame:

```
 for (let i = 0; i < SF_COUNT; i++) {
     if (stars[i].y < 75) {stars[i].op -= 0.001;}    
     else {stars[i].op -= 0.01;}
 }
```

However, what actually happens is that stars **do** animate at different rates, but this difference appears **random** (i.e. not limited to stars at the top part of the canvas). Why? http://jsfiddle.net/Nata_Hamster/6jdnq3ry/

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand the language you're using. Can you try to be more clear?

Comment: @connexo, thank you)) I am working for improving my English) I hope, at this time clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had the strokeStyle as the last step when it should be the first...

Here is your code with my correction:
 
also added a few other minor improvements to make the code more readable

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("drawingCanvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var stars = [];

const SF_COUNT = 500;
context.lineWidth = 1.1;

window.onload = function() {
  changeColor1();
  drawFrame();
}

for (let i = 0; i < SF_COUNT; i++) {
  stars.push({
    x: randomInt(1, canvas.width - 1),
    y: randomInt(0, canvas.height - 1),
    op: 1
  });
}

function randomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min));
}

function snowflake(star) {
  context.strokeStyle = 'rgba(255,255,255,' + star.op + ')';
  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(star.x, star.y);
  context.lineTo(star.x + context.lineWidth, star.y + context.lineWidth);
  context.stroke();
}

function drawFrame() {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  for (let i = 0; i < SF_COUNT; i++)
    snowflake(stars[i]);
  setTimeout(drawFrame, 190);
}

function changeColor1() {
  for (let i = 0; i < SF_COUNT; i++)
    if (stars[i].op > 0)
      stars[i].op -= (stars[i].y < 75) ? 0.002 : 0.01;
  requestAnimationFrame(changeColor1);
}
```

```css
#drawingCanvas {
  height: 170px;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="drawingCanvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Well seen! I also tried to solve the problem but couldn't figure it out (lack of experience with canvas I suppose). Do I understand correctly that what happened was that each star (or snowflake) got assigned the opacity of the previous one because the stroke style was still there?

Comment: @DesperateEi Yeah the title was very misleading

Answer (score 1):

**Bug:**

Right now your `drawFrame` code sets the opacity *after* drawing the star, meaning that the opacity affects the *next* star instead of the current one:

```
...
// draw all SF_COUNT stars
for (let i = 0; i < SF_COUNT; i++) {
    // this draws star i with the *current* context.strokeStyle
    snowflake(stars[i].x, stars[i].y);
    // this sets the context.strokeStyle for star i + 1
    context.strokeStyle = 'rgba(255,255,255,' + stars[i].op + ')';
}
...
```

**Fix:**

Swap the two lines so that you set the color before drawing the star:

```
...
// draw all SF_COUNT stars
for (let i = 0; i < SF_COUNT; i++) {   
    // this sets the context.strokeStyle, changing the opacity of star i
    context.strokeStyle = 'rgba(255,255,255,' + stars[i].op + ')';
    // this draws star i with the new context.strokeStyle
    snowflake(stars[i].x, stars[i].y);
}
...
```

[Here's a fixed codepen.](http://jsfiddle.net/6jdnq3ry/24/)